# Django max_upload_size gets ignored

Tags: python, django, django-models, field

I have this code but for some reason the file size gets ignored, even if I set this directly to ('max_upload_size', 5242880) at formatChecker.py the value seems to get ignored after the upload has happened.

settings.py

```
MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "5242880"
```

formatChecker.py

```
from django.db.models import FileField
from django.forms import forms
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from myproject.settings import MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE


class ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(FileField):
    """
    Same as FileField, but you can specify:
        * content_types - list containing allowed content_types. Example: ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg']
        * max_upload_size - a number indicating the maximum file size allowed for upload.
            2.5MB - 2621440
            5MB - 5242880
            10MB - 10485760
            20MB - 20971520
            50MB - 5242880
            100MB 104857600
            250MB - 214958080
            500MB - 429916160
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.content_types = kwargs.pop('content_types', [])

        super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

        file = data.file
        try:
            content_type = file.content_type
            if content_type in self.content_types:
                if file._size > int(MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE):
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (
                        filesizeformat(MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE), filesizeformat(file._size)))
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Filetype not supported.'))
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return data
```

models.py

```
...
class Post(models.Model):
    postattachment = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(
      blank=True,
      null=True,
      upload_to=get_file_path_user_uploads,
      content_types=['application/pdf',
                     'application/zip',
                     'application/x-rar-compressed',
                     'application/x-tar',
                     'image/gif',
                     'image/jpeg',
                     'image/png',
                     'image/svg+xml',
                     ]
     )
...
```

Any idea why that problem occurs?
Did I forget something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "5242880"` in `setting.py`

then in views file

```
from django.conf import settings
file._size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE
```

or `file._size > int(settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE)`

in init method, it pop two keys, so it doesn't exists

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.content_types = kwargs.pop('content_types', [])
       self.max_upload_size = kwargs.pop('max_upload_size',[])
```

so remove these line

```
self.content_types = kwargs.pop('content_types', [])
self.max_upload_size = kwargs.pop('max_upload_size', [])
```

Comment: Nope ... 
MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 5242880
and MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "5242880"
tryd

Comment: Also not working, sadly. tried different variations of your solution. Feels like max_upload_size does not even exist.

Comment: do i also remove the max_upload_size from the model?

Comment: I tryd again but still not working, i updated my question, do you see any problemes there?

Comment: i cant remove content types or there should be no need for doing this i guess

Comment: Okay, got it fixed with validators, Thanks anyways